bash grep can return an empty space, how to substitute the empty space for a string?
I am attempting to grep an inbox for survey results, in which the subject will include the answer to the following question:
"The answer to your question is ___"
The answered question will take the form of:
"Subject: RE: The answer to your question is yes|no|' '"
I have tries the following in a bash script:
subject=$(cat /var/mail/incoming | grep '^Subject:' | cut  -d' ' -f 9)

I am expecting output similar to the following:
yes
no
no
yes

yes
no

In which there will be spaces where a non-answer occurred, and this is exactly what I see when I grep at the command line.
However, when I store the results in a var, the output is:
yes
no
no
yes
yes
no

How do I detect a space at the end of my grep command and replace it with "none"?
Desired output:
yes
no
no
yes
none
yes
no 


...However, when I store the results in a var, the output is:.. and how do show the output from the var?

have you actually tried the solution suggested in the linked duplicate? Something like echo "$subject" instead of echo $subject?

Also see: Bash array with spaces in elements in case that's your issue.

subject=$( awk '/^Subject:/ { print ($9 ? $9 : "none") }' /var/mail/incoming )

For example:
$ cat file
Subject: RE: The answer to your question is yes
Subject: RE: The answer to your question is no
Subject: RE: The answer to your question is no
Subject: RE: The answer to your question is yes
Subject: RE: The answer to your question is
Subject: RE: The answer to your question is yes
Subject: RE: The answer to your question is no


$ subject=$( awk '/^Subject:/ { print ($9 ? $9 : "none") }' file )


$ echo "$subject"
yes
no
no
yes
none
yes
no

